# How to align Text in TextView for Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have `png` file that seems like:

[image]

I want to create `TextView` that should be like:

[image]

Here is what I did so far:

**Selector speaker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_over" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_disabled" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_default" />
</selector>
```

And this is `TextView`:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speaker"
        android:background="@drawable/speaker"
        android:text="@string/button_speaker"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_incall_button_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.94" />
```

**String**

```
<string name="button_speaker">Speaker</string>
```

I don't know how to align my text to be "Right-Center" + "margin right"

In xCode for iOS it's simple, just to add margin left/right in pixel scale

How  can I do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
android:text="@string/text"
```

use only icon as image..

by using [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) ,The drawable to be drawn to the left of the text.

update:

use padding then

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/micro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.94"
        android:background="@drawable/micro_on"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/button_micro"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_incall_button_color" />
```

Comment: use only the icon instead of full rectangular image.. and as background set the other part as gradient shape

Comment: but if you want to use your current image then i think the only way is to use padding left

Comment: I write the same application like in iOS and use the same images. Can't do that what you want

Answer (score 2):

Try this code and make changes according to you.

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If the volume Icon is combined with the background then the simplest way would be to create a `RelativeLayout` and set this image as it's background. next place a `TextView` in this `RelativeLayout` and give the `TextView` this properties:

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
```

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="your_image" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Speaker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a imageview as the parent here. I have set the text view on top of imageview using a relative layout. You can check the snap shot below. If you are flexible to use a imageview along with textview you can try the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" or android:paddingLeft="80dp"
    // set padding to desired value
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Speaker"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Resulting snap shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourimage"` attribute for this king of designs
here is the detailed specification about that...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft

Hope this will help you.

Comment: if you are having the bg image with integrated sound icon means you cannot set drawableleft.. you can do use any layout and set bg image to layout background and set text view wit the padding ..